Issue with sh:closed true in SHACL for Inherited Classes with Property Restrictions
I'm encountering an issue when using SHACL with sh:closed true in combination with inheritance. Specifically, the problem arises when a subclass has properties that the super class does not.
Here is an example ontology:
onto:prop a owl:DatatypeProperty .

onto:SuperClass a owl:Class .

onto:SubClass
  a               owl:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf onto:SuperClass, 
              [ 
                  a owl:Restriction ;
                  owl:onProperty onto:Prop ;
                  owl:cardinality 1
                  ] .

Example Data:
This statement should evaluate as correct:
ex:ExampleCorrect a onto:SubClass ;
  onto:prop "Text" .

However, these should be incorrect:
ex:ExampleWrong a onto:SubClass ;
  onto:other 1 .

ex:ExampleWrongSuperClass a onto:SuperClass ;
  onto:prop "Text" .

Solutions:
These are the types of shapes I would construct if I wanted to prevent additional properties to be used:
onto:SuperClass_Shape
  a              sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:closed      true ;
  sh:targetClass onto:SuperClass .

onto:SubClass_Shape
  a              sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass onto:SubClass ;
  sh:closed      true ;
  sh:property    [
                   a           sh:PropertyShape ;
                   sh:maxCount 1 ;
                   sh:minCount 1 ;
                   sh:path     onto:prop ;
                   sh:severity sh:Violation
                 ] .

But because the onto:SuperClass_Shape does not enumerate the property onto:prop and sh:closed true is applied , this results in a violation.
I know it is also possible target only a node instead of targeting a whole class as I did above.
onto:SubClass_Shape
  a             sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetNode ex:ExampleCorrect .

But I have thousands of nodes that I want to evaluate at the same time. Enumerating all the data IRIs does not seem like a good solution to me.
I understand that my aim is somewhat contradictory to the logic of SHACL and RDF inheritance.
How can I structure the SHACL shapes to allow the subclass to have its own properties without violating the superclass's closed shape restrictions?
I want to prevent additional properties in all classes but still allow flexibility in sub-classes to define its own properties.
Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated!

sh:closed was (unfortunately) not designed to take subclass relationships into account. But many people have run into similar problems are you did, and there is the extension dash:closedByTypes to address it.
https://datashapes.org/constraints.html#ClosedByTypesConstraintComponent
To use that, you would need a SHACL engine with SHACL-SPARQL support.
The upcoming SHACL 1.2 WG may bring something like this into the SHACL Core vocabulary, see https://github.com/w3c/shacl/issues/43

Thank you very much for your swift answer! I will investigate if this is a good solution for us!
